# SQL Server 2000 - Row of data based on closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have two tables as below and I want to return the rows for `CARE_ID` and `WHO_STATUS` where the `MDT_DATE` is the closest date that is `<=` the earliest `SURGERY_DATE` for each `CARE_ID`.

For instance for `CARE_ID 5` the closest `MDT_DATE` which is `<=` the earliest `SURGERY_DATE` of `18/07/2009` is `17/07/2009` so the `WHO_STATUS` would be 2, and so on.

The script below works fine in SQL Server 2005 but it isn't backwards compatible with SQL Server 2000.

How could I rework this script so it will run in SQL Server 2000?

```
CARE_ID SURGERY_DATE
5       18/07/2009 00:00
5       23/07/2009 00:00
5       23/07/2009 00:00
5       23/07/2009 00:00
5       01/09/2009 00:00
5       03/09/2009 00:00
70      20/07/2009 00:00
70      21/07/2009 00:00
76      03/03/2010 00:00
78      08/07/2009 00:00
81      27/07/2009 00:00
82      27/07/2009 00:00
83      30/07/2009 00:00
86      29/07/2009 00:00
91      30/07/2009 00:00
103     03/08/2009 00:00
106     05/08/2009 00:00
125     07/08/2009 00:00
172     19/05/2010 00:00


CARE_ID MDT_DATE            WHO_STATUS
5       17/07/2009 00:00    2
5       03/11/2009 00:00    1
70      23/03/2010 00:00    0
81      03/11/2009 00:00    1
81      18/11/2009 00:00    1
81      27/11/2009 00:00    3
81      27/03/2010 00:00    1
103     03/12/2008 00:00    0
103     04/01/2009 00:00    2
103     06/01/2010 00:00    1
103     08/02/2010 00:00    1
103     14/01/2013 00:00    1
172     20/07/2009 00:00    4
172     08/01/2010 00:00    3
172     25/09/2010 00:00    1
```

The query (working in SQL Server 2005):

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.WHO_STATUS
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CARE_ID ORDER BY SURGERY_DATE) AS Seq,*
     FROM Table1)t1
      CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 WHO_STATUS FROM Table2
           WHERE CARE_ID = t1.CARE_ID
           AND MDT_DATE < = t1.SURGERY_DATE
           ORDER BY MDT_DATE DESC)t2
WHERE t1.Seq=1
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand: software dinosaurs roam :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Why do people act so surprised when 2000 is mentioned. I have heard of companies having enough money and 
still using 2000 in 2011, regardless of its demerits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 who_status
        from table2 t2
        where t2.care_id = t1.care_id and
              t2.mdt_date <= t1.surgery_date
        order by t2.mdt_date desc
       ) as who_status
from Table1 t1;
```

This will also work in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that when I'm back at work in the morning!